# Find the function $f(t)\neq 0$ such that for all $g(t)$ we have $L\{\frac{d}{dt}(f*g)\}=L\{f\}$

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution

**Question:**

> Find the function $f(t)\neq 0$ such that for all $g(t)$ we have $L\{\frac{d}{dt}(f*g)\}=L\{f\}$

Note: $L$ stands for Laplace transform.

---

**My try**:

$F_1(s):=L\{f*g\}=L\{f\}\times L\{g\}$

$\implies L\{\frac{d}{dt}(f*g)\}=s\times L\{f*g\}-(f*g)(0)=s \times L\{f\} \times L\{g\}-(f*g)(0)=L\{f\}$

I'm not sure, but if $(f*g)(0)=0$, then we have:

$$L\{f\}(sL\{g\}-1)=0$$

At this point, It seems there is nothing to do!

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is possible, if $g(t)=0$ then $f*g=0\implies \dfrac d{dt}(f*g)=0\implies \mathcal{L}(\dfrac d{dt}(f*g))=0\implies \mathcal{L}(f)=0$